# WordPress custom theme installation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have developed a WordPress site using custom HTML using plugins like ACF Pro, Contact Form 7, and woocommerce. Now I want to export the complete theme and install it somewhere else. Please suggest me a plugin and to export that and import to another fresh WordPress. It would have been better if things work exactly like paid plugins, I mean once I install this theme to any fresh WordPress, I get a new option that says install plugins and install demo content. I searched a lot but didn't find anything on how to start this. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a better question for [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write functions that will request unnecessary plugins, i think there is no plugin to automate that functionality.
One example for this is TGM Plugin, [link](https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to transfer/copy WordPress-Websites is the [AllInOne WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) PlugIn.